# Javascript function return : << and |

Tags: javascript

I was looking in the google "Bookmark bubble library" source code when I saw this function

```
/**
* Creates a version number from 4 integer pieces between 0 and 127 (inclusive).
* @param {*=} opt_a The major version.
* @param {*=} opt_b The minor version.
* @param {*=} opt_c The revision number.
* @param {*=} opt_d The build number.
* @return {number} A representation of the version.
* @private
*/
google.bookmarkbubble.Bubble.prototype.getVersion_ = function(opt_a, opt_b,opt_c, opt_d) {
// We want to allow implicit conversion of any type to number while avoiding
// compiler warnings about the type.
return /** @type {number} */ (opt_a) << 21 |
  /** @type {number} */ (opt_b) << 14 |
  /** @type {number} */ (opt_c) << 7 |
  /** @type {number} */ (opt_d);
};
```

I don't understand the double sign '<<' and the single '|'

if anybody understand, can he please increase my javascript knowledge and tell me how this "return" work ?

Thanks

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: << is bitwise 'shift left' operator and | is bitwise 'or' operator

Comment: thanks, elclanrs and Joseph. Please answer my post so I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple JavaScript to see what is going on (using .toString(2) returns the binary representation of a number):

```
console.log((8).toString(2));
> 1000
console.log((8>>1).toString(2));
> 0100 (shift right one space)
console.log((8<<1).toString(2));
> 10000 (shift left one space)
console.log((8|9|5).toString(2));
> 1101 (combines the 3 numbers like this:

  1000
  1001
  0101
  ====
  1101 if any digit is 1 then return a 1 in that digit)
```